# Random SSH Agent Generates on Boot in tmp Directory Even with Networking Disabled

Tags: netstat, ssh-agent, ipsec

On a recently installed Debian system I noticed that every boot, even with no networking, a folder and empty socket file are generated in `/tmp/ssh-(random_letters)/agent.xxx`.

On every boot the random letters assigned to the folder name and random numbers assigned to the socket file change.

On this system there is no VPN or tunneling setup, but netstat shows a process for `/var/run/charon.ctl` listening on a unix 2 STREAM.

It also shows `ipsec-nat-t` and `isakmp` listening over UDP for local address `0.0.0.0` and foreign address `0.0.0.0:*`.

If I run `netstat -ap | grep` (number assigned to empty socket file) it produces a bunch of matches running on unix 2 and 3.

Examples:

```
@/tmp/.ICE-unix/(number assigned to socket) x8

/tmp/.ICE-unix/(number assigned to socket) x1
```

All of them are preceded by reference to:

```
(number assigned to socket)/x-session-manager.
```

And then there are another 5 listings same format but no path referenced. All connected, stream. And one more connected for dgram.

**Is this normal?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those things look completely normal.

The SSH agent is started on login as part of your graphical desktop. Yes it doesn't care whether you have an Ethernet cable or not (nor should it). Yes it gets a random socket address every time.

The Charon socket will be listening whenever Charon (the strongSwan daemon) is running. Whether it has any connections set up or not is irrelevant – if the overall service was configured to start on boot, it'll start on boot, just like Apache will start even if you don't really have a website yet.

(If you're running Debian it indeed configures any newly installed service to start on boot, whether the admin wants it or not...)

The two UDP listeners are IKE (the IPsec handshake protocol), which is literally Charon's job. If it's running, it'll listen for IKE packets.

`ICE-unix` sockets are used by the X11 session manager (e.g. gnome-session), as the traditional X11 session management protocol is built on top of "Inter-Client Exchange" IPC system (not to be confused with the ICE from STUN/WebRTC which is a different thing).

The one with a `@` prefix is an *abstract* socket, which doesn't correspond to anything in the filesystem; abstract socket names don't necessarily look like paths at all. X11 uses both regular and abstract sockets for... legacy reasons.

The nameless sockets are *client* sockets. The listener socket has a path – client sockets don't. But they'll show up in netstat because showing all sockets is what netstat does.